# Capistrano git:wrapper keeps asking for ssh passphrase

Tags: git, drupal, web-deployment, ssh-keys, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy a Drupal application using Capistrano 3.3.5 (along with net-ssh 3.2.0). My deployment workstation is Windows running git-bash. I also started up ssh-agent, and ran ssh-add for my private key.

Then I ran:

```
> cap development deploy
```

And it asked me for a password for my private key.

```
Enter passphrase for C:/Users/jgodse/.ssh/id_rsa: my_password
```

When I typed in "my_password" as my SSH key password, it hung. I did a CTRL-C, and it then said:

```
bash: my_password: command not found
```

Then I tried:

```
> cap development --dry-run
```

After hitting return a couple of times, I got a dry-run log. The first few lines looked like this:

```
$ cap development deploy --dry-run
There was a problem tracking statistics, please report to     https://github.com/capistrano/stats

 INFO [4b085395] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/ as ubuntu@www.myapp.com
 DEBUG [4b085395] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/
 INFO [b5f607a2] Running /usr/bin/env #<StringIO:0x3b9e4d0> /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh as ubuntu@www.myapp.com
 DEBUG [b5f607a2] Command: /usr/bin/env #<StringIO:0x3b9e4d0> /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh
 INFO [c0895cc9] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh as ubuntu@www.myapp.com
```

Then I adjusted the Capfile to add the statement:

```
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
```

No change.

I then upgraded to capistrano 3.5.0, and unstalled capistrano-stats, and locked the version to 3.5.0.

```
> cap development deploy --dry-run
```

I got:

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/
      02 #<StringIO:0x28c7238> /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh
      03 chmod +rx /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh
```

This told me that the git:wrapper task might be troublesome. Then I ran:

```
> cap development git:wrapper
```

I got:

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/
Enter passphrase for C:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

I got the same result as before when I typed the password. Then I did:

```
> cap development git:wrapper --dry-run
```

I got:

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp/myapp/
      02 #<StringIO:0x28e2448> /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh
      03 chmod +rx /tmp/myapp/git-ssh.sh
```

At this point it looks like the git:wrapper task is not working and it could be because step 2 has this StringIO: thing in it, which looks like a Ruby object id instead of an actual Bash command. Or it could be something else.

Are there any ways to work around this so that my deployment doesn't erroneously ask me to type in my password?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set up SSH Agent so that your key's passphrase is not requested on deploy.

The Capistrano documentation has the details of doing this: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/

A short version might look something like:

Run:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
# It'll prompt you for your password here.
cap dev deploy # Or whatever you run to execute Capistrano.
```

At this point, you should be able to run Capistrano in this shell without being prompted for a password.

If this is useful, you may want to look up how to set up your shell to share an ssh-agent session across terminals.

Comment: As I said in the second line of the problem, I did that, and it still didn't work.

Comment: If it asked for your password, you don't have ssh agent actually working. With that said, I had overlooked that you are using Windows. In my mind, all bets are off on that OS, so I have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: It gets better. I ran it on Linux, and it worked.   :(

Comment: This is the only thing that could get me past the "Enter your passphrase" stage. The key is to not give `ssh-add` the path to any key and let it do it's own thing